# Why are argc and argv not const?

Tags: c, standards, program-entry-point

The C standard allows these 2 signatures for the main function:

```
int main (void);
int main (int argc, char* argv[]);
```

It also specifies that:

> The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv
>   array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored
>   values between program startup and program termination.

I am surprised by that choice. I think it would have been more natural to make `argc` and `argv` `const`. It is often regarded as bad practice to modify these variables.

Am I missing something? Why has that choice been made?

Comment: My question is not restricted to argc, and is asked for C, not C++.

Comment: @DevShark Did you not read the duplicate? It is about history (i.e. C) and specifically mentions that the signature of `main` predates `const`.

Comment: Although little used, there is a third signature available:  `int main( int argc, char* argv[], char * env[] )`

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of that.